# How to display "More games" page via ChartBoost in iOS?

Tags: ios, ads, chartboost

I'm trying to integrate ChartBoost in my app and single ads are displaying OK.

This is the initial setup:

```
ChartBoost *cb = [ChartBoost sharedChartBoost];
cb.delegate = self;
cb.appId = CHARBOOST_APP_ID;
cb.appSignature = CHARBOOST_APP_SIGNATURE;

[cb showInterstitial];
```

But when I'm trying to display the "More apps" page, using the [ChartBoost tutorial](http://chartboost.com/support/sdk), I don't get the response.

```
-(IBAction) switchToMoreGames: (id) sender{
    ChartBoost* cb = [ChartBoost sharedChartBoost];
    cb.delegate = self;
    [cb cacheMoreApps];
    [cb showMoreApps];
}
```

I'd be very appreciative for any kind of help I can get, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to fix your issue, but I'm wondering if you had to do anything else to get the ads displaying ok? I've just tried to set everything up, and my code looks the same as yours (the top part). However nothing appears either in the simulator or on my device. I've added the app to my CB account, and also have set up a campaign, but still nothing :-(

Comment: Scratch that. There must be some kind of delay between setting up and having the ads appear - they just started appearing without me changing anything :-)

Comment: You should post the answer you found as an answer rather than updating the question. You can also accept your own answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: For anyone reading the code in the question: The call to cacheMoreApps should go in the setup code, not the code to actually show the More Apps screen. The point of caching it is so that it is already loaded when you want to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there were many requests for me to answer my own question rather than update it, I have created this answer.

To add "More apps" page you have to go to "Edit your app", then click "More apps page" tab and type the name of your campaign in the input field of the iPhone, which is showing on the right.